# maven-tomcat7-plugin requires mvn install

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have looked around on stack overflow and other forums but no one seems to have asked this specific problem. I am running multiple sub WAR packages from a single POM file. To run them, I use `mvn tomcat7:run`. This command works fine if I have first run `mvn install` but I would like to be able to use `mvn package` instead. It shouldn't be necessary to install my own web apps in a local repository before running them through the plugin, right?

My project structure is as follows:

```
parent
 ├─ subProject1
 └─ subProject2
```

The parent project only contains a POM.xml file with the following plugin data and module data:

```
<modules>
    <module>subProject1</module>
    <module>subProject2</module>
</modules>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <webapps>
                    <webapp>
                        <groupId>group.id.of.project</groupId>
                        <artifactId>subProject1</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <contextPath>/subProject1</contextPath>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                    </webapp>
                    <webapp>
                        <groupId>group.id.of.project</groupId>
                        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <contextPath>/subProject2</contextPath>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                    </webapp>
                </webapps>
                <tomcatUsers>${basedir}/tomcat-users.xml</tomcatUsers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Each of the subprojects has their own pom that doesn't reference the tomcat plugin at all. Could that be part of the issue? Or is there some way of specifying folders to look in for the plugin that doesn't affect the global plugin properties but just the properties for the specific build?

The specific error I get when I run `mvn tomcat7:run` is:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) on project parent: Unable to find artifact. Could not find artifact group.id.of.project:subProject1:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have 3 projects. In which of them do you run `mvn tomcat7:run` and `mvn install|package`? You name the top project `parent`. Are there `<parent>` sections in your `subProject`s' POMs?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I run both `mvn tomcat7:run` and `mvn install|package` in the parent project. The sub projects do have `<parent>` definitions.